# Removing column based on the content of the cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to delete the whole column in a DataGridView based on a certain condition. My DataGridView columns consists of numbers (1,2 and 3) the condition would be to delete all columns that does not contain (1,2 and 3). For Example if the column has only (1 and 3) it should be deleted.

How do I Overcome this? as many threads I went through only cover when you are certain of an index like below.

```
myGridView.columns.RemoveAt(index);
```

Some suggest hiding columns and thats not what I want, I want to completely remove the column from the DataGridView.

Comment: Problem is not how to remove the columns. Problem is how do you discover the condition to be true for a particular column. Better work with the DataSource used

Comment: @Steve how do I go on about that? FYI I populated the DataGridView with an Excel spreadsheet that I upload.

Comment: I suppose that you have loaded the Excel in a DataTable. If it is so, the DataTable has a Select method that you can use to filter the rows (like a WHERE statement)

Comment: @Steve that's the case but the we need to view the Excel sheet first before manipulating it or starting to delete. Hence we upload first, and set the criteria before deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's better to do the job using data source of the `DataGridView`, but if the control is not bound to a data source, you can also use linq to get values from columns and check for some criteria, for example:

```
dgv1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
        var values = dgv1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
            .Select(r=>r.Cells[c.Index].Value).ToList();
        if (!values.Contains(1)) //your custom criteria
            dgv1.Columns.Remove(c);
    });
```

Here is a really simple test. Load `dgv1` this way:

```
dgv1.ColumnCount = 2;
dgv1.Rows.Add(1, 2); 
dgv1.Rows.Add(3, 4);
```

Then use above code to delete columns and it just removes the last column.

Comment: Sample code, removes all columns which doesn't contain `1` in any of their cells.

Comment: thanx, but it actually deletes all columns I've tried it. Or after deleting do I have to do something else? Like refreshing the grid?

Comment: It's just an example and deletes all columns which not contain `1`. You can use any criteria which you need.

Comment: See the edit. Use `1` instead of `"1"`. As I said, it's just an example, I tested it using strings. But in your case, you need number, like I did in edited answer.

Comment: Here is a really simple test. Load `dgv1` this way: `dgv1.ColumnCount = 2;  dgv1.Rows.Add(1, 2); dgv1.Rows.Add(3, 4);` Then use above code to delete columns and it just removes the last column.